# Australian Transit-Visa question

Tags: indian-citizens, australia, transit-visas

I am an Indian citizen currently in NZ and I need to travel to India really fast.

The cheapest flight I could find was a China Airlines that will be stopping at Sydney for a refuel. I know that Indian passports need Transit Visa when travelling through  Aus but, do you still need it if you don't have to deboard the plane and it's only stopping for a 2 min refuel?

Comment: The answers in that suggested duplicate are contradicting IMHO so be careful before dupe-closing this Q.

Comment: It takes more than two minutes to refuel a jet airliner.

Comment: Australia requires some nationalities to have a transit visa, even to transit airside. This is covered in the suggested dupe, though inexplicably the highest voted answer fails to mention it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton that suggested dupe does not address the refuel stop part of this Q.

Comment: I am pretty sure that Tom's answer to the duplicate question with 13 upvotes is wrong. Even if the Australian Border Protection's visa information pages does not mention technical stops without the need to disembark explicitely, there is also nothing indicating that you in such a situtation are excempt from the transit visa requirement for Indian citizens.

Comment: @mts Yeah, better go with the other one then.

Comment: I agree with @Tor-EinarJarnbjo and I have left [a comment saying as much](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39415/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-technical-stop-in-australia#comment174656_39418) there. Australian immigration need not go through the aircraft, the OP could still be denied boarding in NZ by the airline gate agent.

Comment: Looking at CI flights the itinerary seems to be AKL-BNE-TPE-DEL and the "refuel stop" you claim is 1:15h. It is also possible to book BNE-TPE-DEL as well as AKL-BNE on the same flight, so it is not a refuel stop and you would be able to get off the plane in Australia. I think that changes the picture!

Comment: @pnuts It is not up to me to find out how the Australian Border Protection should enforce their visa rules. In the other question, there is another answer with first hand experience of being denied boarding due to lack of a required transit visa in a similar situation. The Australian embassy confirmed that the transit visa requirement was indeed correct.

Comment: Do you know for sure that you don't get off the plane? Fueling stops are more than a couple of minutes: you could be taking on more than 100 tons of fuel. Usually (though not always), passengers are taken off the plane before it is refuelled. The exceptions are usually short-distance flights on tight turnarounds, and this is not one of those.